# Moving Only Subscriptions from SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have moved reports from SSRS 2008 to SSRS 2012 manually by downloading and uploading reports(I couldn't restore the whole ReportServer DB since there are some existing reports in destination)

Now, I have to move subscriptions as well. Can anyone suggest, how to move only subscriptions. I have almost 180 subscriptions and it is hard to move them manually.

Can I export dbo.subscriptions from source to destination. Does it work?

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, no.

The longer answer is: maybe, if you're willing to do a lot of work tracing back connections on the old server instance.

You can extract (via query) the details of the subscriptions easily:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Subscriptions;
```

The big problem is linking each subscription entry to the correct report.  If you look at the output of that query, the subscriptions are linked to reports (and other items) by way of GUIDs, which are unique to every SSRS instance.